# i need help using the info from other classes in a window?

Tags: java

```
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class CoffeeHomework{



public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setSize(1280, 720);
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.setTitle("Coffee Program");

}  }
```

I need to get the info from those two classes to show up on a window xc im stumped.
i keep getting problems everytime i try something different so i went back to this .
im fifteen i just picked up programming again recently and yah im just saying all this stuff kuz it wouldnt let me post tada.

```
    class CoffeeReturn{

 public static double CoffeeCode(double code){

     double price = 0.0;

     if(code == 1101101){

         price = 25.50;


     }
    return price;



}

 public String CoffeeDesc(double code){
     String desc = "Black Coffee";
          if(code == 1101101){
        return desc;


         }
          else{ return "invalid code"; }    

     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setSize(1280, 720);
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.setTitle("Coffee Program");
    CoffeeReturn yourCoffeeReturn = new CoffeeReturn();
    yourCoffeeReturn.CoffeeDesc(123456);
    CoffeeReturn.CoffeeCode(123456); // this is statis so no need to instantiate a new CoffeeReturn.

}  }
```